# Passing Array as argument to a new thread in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I am attempting to pass an array as an argument to a function in a new thread using pthread_create, is this possible? I have an array of integers and a calculate average method that is called from the create thread method but I cannot seem to pass my array into the method correctly. Here is my code:
    int nums[];

```
int average;

int size = 0;


void *calcAvg(int *nums[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /* initialize an array of the integers to be passed */
    nums[argc - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++){
        nums[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
        size++;
    }

    /* Thread Identifier */
    pthread_t avgThread;

    pthread_create(&avgThread, NULL, calcAvg, nums);

    pthread_join(avgThread, NULL);

    printf("average= %d", average);
}

void *calcAvg(int *nums[]){
    int sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    average = sum / (size);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `nums` in `main` is not even declared properly, it seems.

Comment: You should really identify whether you've got a compile-time, link-time or run-time problem.  The code shown shouldn't be compiling without warnings; if it is, you need to increase the warnings level on your compilations.  And you should fix the warnings; remember, the C compiler probably knows more about C than you do.

Comment: The function for a thread should have the signature `void *thread_function(void *arg)` — a function that takes a 'universal pointer' (pointer to `void`) as an argument and returns a pointer to `void`.  Your `calcAvg()` function doesn't match that, so the solution by [michaeltang](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1884138/michaeltang) fixes that problem. There's no particular reason to use `pthread_exit(0);` at the end; were it my code, I'd use `return 0;` — but the net result is the same except that the compiler won't complain about not returning a value from a function that is supposed to do so.

Comment: Within the function, the cast from `void *` to `int *` is legitimate given that the input was originally an `int` array, which is converted first to an `int` pointer (a pointer to the first element of the array) and then to a `void` pointer to match the function prototype.  Your declaration using `int *nums[]` manages to use two levels of pointer where only one is required; you would have done better with `int *nums` or `int nums[]` — there are equivalent when used in a function declaration or definition (but only in that context — elsewhere, they are rather different).

Comment: The residual issue is a matter of style — and thread-safety. You use two global variables, `size` and `average`.  Given that your main thread goes to sleep while the only child thread is executing, there is no problem.  If you had two or more child threads, you would need to worry about whether it was safe to use the variables.  Given that `size` is fixed once the threads start (so they'd only read it), then that would be OK.  However, if multiple threads are accessing `average`, you really need a mutex or something similar to protect it from concurrent access.

Comment: Arguably, with multiple threads, you would do better to create a structure to hold the number of integers, a pointer to the array of integers, and the average, and then pass a pointer to a separate structure for each thread.  Of course, you might then just use the threads to compute the sum and compute the average in the main code from the multiple returned values.  Or you might find some other way to handle the processing.  In general, though, if you have threads writing to a global variable, you have to ensure proper access with mutexes or the equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler that clears things up a ton!

Answer (score 10):

there is lots of problem in your code, i fix some to compile
hope it will help

compile: gcc -o main main.c -lpthread

execute: ./main 2 5

output: 3

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int average;

int size = 0;


void *calcAvg(void *arg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  /* initialize an array of the integers to be passed */
  int *nums = (int*)malloc((argc - 1)*sizeof(int));
  int i = 1;
  for(i = 1; i < argc ; i++){
    nums[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    size++;
  }

  /* Thread Identifier */
  pthread_t avgThread;

  pthread_create(&avgThread, NULL, calcAvg, (void*)nums);

  pthread_join(avgThread, NULL);
  printf("average = %d \n",average);
  free(nums);

}
void *calcAvg(void *arg){
  int *val_p = (int *) arg;
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for( i = 0; i < size; i++){
    sum += val_p[i];
  }
  average = sum / (size);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++, so technically you should be using `gcc` and not `g++` to compile.  You should also use either a VLA (as the original code attempted to do) or `malloc()` or a range check and a static array rather than using `new`.

Comment: Thank you, so you must cast the array to a void type? I am still confused in C what the * does exactly. So you're casting the array to a void type, and the * has something to do with declaring it as a pointer, can you elaborate on that please? Thank you!

Comment: and is it best practice to cast things to a void type and then cast them back when passing args?

Comment: @justinhenricks , it is required when a function used as callback function of thread, you may consider nums as a pointer of int. it think you should read the meaning and usage of * in book

Comment: This is a solution to a particular problem and doesn't answer the question posed. Maybe this helped OP but I don't think this is useful to anyone else in the community. IMHO this answer should be removed or modified.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
void *calcAvg(int *nums[]){
    int sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    average = sum / (size);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

to

```
void *calcAvg(void *arg){
    int *val_p = (int *) arg;
    int sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += val_p[i];
    }
    average = sum / (size);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue that 'pthread_create()' takes a void pointer as its last argument. You are trying to pass to it an array of pointers to integers. Issue "man pthread_create" at the terminal to see the argument types you should be passing.

What you really want to do is just pass the of array integers to the thread. In C, array indexing is just notation for pointer arithmetic. Writing `nums[i]` is equivalint to `&nums[0] + i` or just `nums+i`. The last case works because the name of an array in C can be used as a pointer to the first element of the array.

change `void *calcAvg(int *nums[])` to `void *calcAvg(void* thread_args)`. Then in 'calcAvg' write `int *nums = (int*)thread_args`. Now you can use `nums` in that function just as if you had called `calcAvg(nums)`, which in in essence you have done.

Comment: Given a prototype in scope, the compiler will automatically convert the `int *` to a `void *` in the call. In fact, that should not provoke a warning from the compiler.  What should provoke a warning is passing `void (*func)(int *)` function pointer to a routine expecting a `void (*func)(void *)`.